# How can I fetch core data with grouping?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have started working on an application which uses `CoreData` to store data locally.

Now, I need to fetch records from one model using the group by clause.

Example. Fetch records group by status (Processed, Pending, Failed, etc).

```
 fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "statusInt == %d",Status.sending.rawValue)

    sendingFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: DBManager.shared.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have a look at `NSFetchedResultsController`. That's the easiest way of doing this. There are various tutorials for using this.

Comment: Core Data's model is more about objects than records.  If you want to do raw database operations, you might be better to use a DB directly.

Comment: @Fogmeister I had updated question with my code

Comment: @SunnyShah you need to use the `sectionNameKeyPath` what you are looking for is `sections` not `groups`. But yeah, take a look at the docs for NSFRC and look at the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter.

Comment: @PhillipMills there are no raw database operations here. Just fetching data from CoreData...?

Comment: @Fogmeister How can I use sectionNameKeyPath in my case

Comment: @SunnyShah you need to section the data by a property. So have a property called `status` with values `1 = Processed, 2 = Pending, 3 = Failed, etc...` and then use `status` as the `sectionNameKeyPath`.